# How do I properly scale a Screen Space Overlay with its children?

Tags: unity

I have a Canvas on which 3 Text objects are hosted.

These text objects are anchored so that they move and scale with the canvas if the canvas has "World Space" render mode.

Now I need to set the Canvas to Screen Space overlay. 
This causes the canvas to fill the entire screen.

I can resize / scale it user either the Panel's RectTransform's width / height or its Scale x / y.

Neither option scales or positions the Text objects as previously when the RenderMode was "World Space".

How is this properly achieve?

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like for me:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your text objects aren't children of the panel...

Comment: Thank you! I parented them, and now it works fine!